# Get the most frequently occurring number in a bash array

Tags: bash

I needed to find the most frequent number in an array. I did it this way:

```
# our array, the most frequent value is 55
declare -a array=(44 55 55 55 66 66)

# counting unque string with uniq and then sorting as numbers
array=($(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"| uniq -c | sort -n -r))

# printing 2nd element of array, as the first one - number of occurencies
printf ${array[1]}
```

Is it a better/more beautiful way to do it, instead of building a weird array(2nd step) which consists mixed counts and numbers together?

And am I doing sorting correctly? (`uniq` returns values in 2 columns, so I'm not sure how it chooses the column)

Comment: Note that `uniq` needs its input to be sorted, so you may need to insert another call to `sort` before `uniq` in the pipeline.

Comment: Actually, this is pretty good, provided that the input is pre-sorted.  The logic doesn't work with out-of-order data.  Remember, `bash` is a shell, not really intended as a general-purpose programming language.  It's designed to handle program execution and required data movements: command arguments, piping data, etc.

Comment: @Prune I know, just need to alter some script, I don't want to rewrite it in another language

Comment: actually input doesn't need to be sorted but repeated entries must be adjacent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I had to do this in `bash`, I would use `awk` to skip sorting anything and just count the elements:

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | awk '{
     if (++arr[$0] > max) {
       max=arr[$0];
       ans=$0
     }
   } 
   END {print ans}'
```

You can also implement the same algorithm in `bash` 4 or later using an associative array:

```
# These don't strictly need to be initialized, but it's safer
# to ensure they don't already have values.
declare -A counts=()
max=0
ans=
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
  if ((++counts[$i] > max)); then
    max=${counts[$i]}
    ans=$i
  fi
done
printf '%s\n' "$ans"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to use **awk** to do this, you can still do it with **sort** and **uniq** but be careful, you need to have the input **ALREADY** sorted before counting. Otherwise it will not work. For instance :

```
declare -a array=(34 3 45 45 66 55 44 55 55 55 66 45 45 8 6 45 45 66 32 9 18)
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | sort -n -r | uniq -c | sort -n -r | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

where for the given input the code correctly extracts the most repeated number, but in the sample you gave it will not work and it will tell 55 is the most repeated number, although thats wrong, since its clearly 45, but **uniq** only counts continuous items, if they are sparse it will count them incorrectly.

Regads!

Answer (score 2):

A bit more verbose version of chepner's logic using associative arrays on `bash` v4+ onward. We build the associative array `hashMap` with key as array element and the count of its occurrence as the value. Once we build the array, we find from the array having the max count and retrieve its value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a array=(44 55 55 55 66 66)
declare -A hashMap
declare -i max=0

for element in "${array[@]}"; do
    ((hashMap["$element"]++))
done

for key in "${!hashMap[@]}"; do
    (( "${hashMap[$key]}" > max )) && { max="${hashMap[$key]}"; element="$key" ; }
done

printf '%d\n' "$element"
```

Answer (score 1):

another minimalist `awk`

```
$ awk '{for(mi=i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(a[$mi]<++a[$i]) mi=i; print $mi}' <<< "${array[@]}"
```